# The system of three trigonometric equations in three unknowns.

Tags: trigonometry

Need help solving a system of three trigonometric equations in three unknowns. These equations are used to find the coordinates $φ_s$, $θ_s$ and time $t_s$ at the signal source.

($φ_1$, $θ_1$); ($φ_2$, $θ_2$); ($φ_3$, $θ_3$) - coordinates of the three points to which the signal arrived.
$t_1$, $t_2$, $t_3$ - the time at which the signal arrived at each of the three points.
V - is the speed of signal propagation.
R - distance.

$$\cos φ_1\cos θ_1 \cos φ_s \cos θ_s+ \cos φ_1 \sin θ_1 \cos φ_s \sin θ_s +\sin φ_1 \sin φ_s =\cos (\frac{V}{R}(t_1-t_s))$$

$$\cos φ_2 \cos θ_2 \cos φ_s \cos θ_s+ \cos φ_2 \sin θ_2 \cos φ_s \sin θ_s +\sin φ_2  \sin φ_s=\cos(\frac{V}{R}(t_2-t_s))$$

$$\cos φ_3 \cos θ_3 \cos φ_s \cos θ_s +\cos φ_3 \sin θ_3 \cos φ_s \sin θ_s +\sin φ_3 \sin φ_s=\cos(\frac{V}{R}(t_3-t_s))$$

What is the value of $φ_s$, $θ_s$, $t_s$ based on this system?

Comment: I had a go at fixing some of the LaTeX to make your equations more readable. It doesn't all seem to have worked, so I will let someone more knowledgeable with the code see if they can fix my errors. Oddly, the early subscripts seem to be fine, it is in the product of trig functions that things didn't seem to work as well.

Comment: You can factor

$$
\cos \varphi_1 \cos \varphi_s \left( \cos \theta_1  \cos \theta_s+
 \sin\theta_1  \sin\theta_s \right) + \sin\varphi_1 \sin\theta_s=\cos\left(\frac{V}{R}(t_1-t_s)\right)
$$

and then divide by $\cos \varphi_1$ to get

$$
 \cos \varphi_s \left( \cos \theta_1  \cos \theta_s+
 \sin\theta_1  \sin\theta_s \right) + \tan\varphi_1 \sin\theta_s=
\frac{\cos\left(\frac{V}{R}(t_1-t_s)\right)}{\cos \varphi_1}
$$

I think if you rename some parts, then you could get to a neater form. Just some ideas ...

Comment: The equation aims to find the signal source on a spherical surface.

R here is the distance to the center of the sphere. Speed V is a constant. As well as the coordinates of the three points at which this signal was recorded.

Comment: If you define $\tau_i = \frac VRt_i$, and $\mathbf v_i = (\cos\varphi_i\cos\theta_i, \cos\varphi_i\sin\theta_i, \sin\phi_i)$, for $i = 1,2,3,s$, then each of the $\mathbf v_i$ are points on $S^2$, the unit sphere in $\Bbb R^3$, and the three equations says that $\tau_i - \tau_s$ is the angle between $\mathbf v_i$ and $\mathbf v_s$. It might help to think of this geometrically.